# uwsgi py-autoreload not being honored

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have a flask app.  When I run wsgi.py flask runs in debug mode and all changes I make to any of my view files, Flask reloads.  When I run:

> "uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5050 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app"

For some reason uwsgi is not telling Flask to reload although I have the

> "py-autoreload = 1"

option set in the .ini file.  The uwsgi.ini and the wsgi.py are in the root dir and the **init**.py is in sub directory called flask project where I have my views.  Not sure what I am missing.

```
_________________uwsgi.ini_________________
[uwsgi]

module = wsgi:app
master = true
processes = 5


buffer-size = 32768

http = 0.0.0.0:5000

stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0

stderr_logfile=/dev/stdout
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

py-autoreload = 1

_________________wsgi.py_________________
from flask_project import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


_________________flaskproject/__init__.py_________________
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.wsgi_app = DebuggedApplication(app.wsgi_app, True)

    app.debug = True

    return app
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I was not calling the .ini file directly.  I called it by

> uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini

and now auto-reload is working.